# ReactNative: failed to call functions from NativeModules

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, react-native

I'm requiring the photo permission in IOS. 
In my code, I have added PermissionManager.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PermissionManager:NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

and PermissionManager.m:

```
#import "PermissionManager.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

@implementation PermissionManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(); 

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(photoPermission:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve 
reject:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject) { 
  ALAuthorizationStatus author = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];  
  if (author == ALAuthorizationStatusRestricted || author ==ALAuthorizationStatusDenied)
  {
    reject(@"500",@"Photo access denied",nil);    
  }else {
    resolve(@YES);    
  }
}

@end
```

This files are added at same level as AppDelegate.m file via XCode.
In my javascript code i do this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
manager = NativeModules.PermissionManager;
```

But `PermissionManager` is undefined shown in the Debugger.
Then I try to call the funtion in it:

```
const photoPermission = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        manager.photoPermission().then(data => {
            resolve(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

When I run the simulator, it warns:

> Cannot read property 'photoPermission' of undefined.

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You have typos: "NSobject" => "NSObject", 
also #import "PermissionsManager.h" => #import "PermissionManager.h"
and "@implementation PermissionsManager" => "@implementation PermissionManager"

Comment: ...and you have missing @end at the end of the PermissionManager.m.

Comment: Thanks for your rectifying! They are my typos indeed, and I have changed it. But my code is correct and it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I added it in my project and it works if I fix the typos